# How To Apply Thin-Plate Spline (TPS) Mapping To Images In Swift

Tags: swift, image-morphology

I am looking for a way to apply TPS mapping/deforming to 2D images in Swift 4. I have been googling around, but there is very little on the subject, and from what I can tell nothing at all in the Swift language ecosystem.